# key fob not recongized after car sitting with dead battery

Tags: hyundai, key, fob, sonata

2011 Hyundai Sonata   Car sitting for long period. New car battery was installed, new battery in key fob.  Car shows no key detected. Will not work on door locks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure it will require the fob to be re-paired with the vehicle ... not "repaired" but to be "paired again". (Sorry for being pedantic ... just wanted to be clear.)

According to [this website](https://www.keylessentryremotefob.com/blog/2015/03/2011-hyundai-sonata-key-fob-remote.html):

> There is no onboard programming procedure for this vehicle. This vehicle requires special equipment be connected to the vehicle to program the keyless remote. Try a locksmith before the dealership, they are usually 50% the cost.

I've not heard of vehicles losing their pairing because of losing the battery, but this seems the most likely culprit.